# GCP Terraform authorization, error 403 permission issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions

I am trying to create a Label module for GCP using Terraform. I was using Visual Studio code to write the script. What happened that Visual Studio code got linked to my other GCP account and now when I am trying to create a bucket in GCP, it is correctly targeting the right project but saying that source (my other GCP account) does not have permission to create bucket (which is right).

But now I don't know how to connect using right source so that it understand that I am an authenticated user.

Comment: first check your permissions from cloud console then in your shell, run `gcloud auth login` & `gcloud auth application-default login`

Comment: Can you create the bucket manually out of terraform?